# Cypher - Best way to create relationships between two arrays of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two arrays of nodes

```
TYPE1 : [Node1, Node2, ...NodeN]
TYPE2 : [OtherNode1, OtherNode2....OtherNodeN]
```

I'm trying to connect each TYPE1 node to its corresponding TYPE2 node as follows.

```
(Node1) -[:RELATED_TO] -> (OtherNode1)
```

It's a simple one-to-one correspondence.

I used

```
MATCH (x:TYPE1),(y:TYPE2)
with x, y
with COLLECT(x) as n1, COLLECT(y) as n2
FOREACH(i in RANGE(0, 9) |
   CREATE (n1[i])-[:RELATED_TO]->(n2[i])
)
```

which fails with

*Error: Invalid input '[': expected an identifier character, node labels, a property map, ')' or a relationship pattern (line 4, column 21)*

I have two questions.

1. What am I doing wrong in the query?
2. What is the best way to accomplish what I'm doing?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do the corresponding nodes have a shared property that you can compare? For example, is there something where Node1.id = OtherNode1.id?

Comment: From your example, it seems you're wanting to connect one `TYPE1` node with exactly one `TYPE2` node, but you _don't care which_ (because the `MATCH` will return things in arbitrary order). It's possible to write a query to do that, if you really want, but I imagine you've instead got some way to tell _which_ `TYPE1` _node belongs to which_ `TYPE2` _node_?

Comment: Chris, Thanks for pointing that out....I need to connect them in order...because they are created in sorted order. So, to clarify, the order is important.

Comment: Nicole, there's no further information available re. shared properties.

Comment: Done....I don't have enough reputation to upvote though :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the following example data:

```
FOREACH (i IN range(1,10) | CREATE (:TYPE1), (:TYPE2))
```

Because you aren't interested in ordering your collections by any properties, you'll just be joining nodes in whatever order they are found by `MATCH`. The following query will do (what I think) you are trying to do, though it is inelegant:

```
MATCH (x:TYPE1), (y:TYPE2)
WITH COLLECT(DISTINCT x) AS n1, COLLECT(DISTINCT y) AS n2
WHERE LENGTH(n1) = LENGTH(n2)
FOREACH (i IN RANGE(0, LENGTH(n1) - 1) |
    FOREACH (node IN [n1[i]] |
        FOREACH (othernode IN [n2[i]] |
            MERGE (node)-[:RELATED_TO]-(othernode)
        )
    )
)
```

Browser view post-query:

[image]